# Program skips user input

Tags: c++

I was writing a simple calculator in c,whereby the user inputs two numbers and afterward choose the operation to apply on them.(Mul,Add,Div,Sub)The program works except it skips the part where its supposed to take user input for the operand.what am i doing wrong

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;

using namespace std;

int main() {

char Operative[100];

int a;
int b;
int c;


printf("Enter First Number\n");
scanf("%d",&a);

printf("Enter First Number\n");
scanf("%d",&b);

printf("\nPlease Enter Operation(M,A,D,S)");
gets(Operative);

//getline(cin,Operative);

if (Operative == "M")
{
    c = a*b;
    printf("Multiplication value is %d",c);

}

else if (Operative == "A")
{
    c = a+b;
    printf("Addition value is %d",c);

}

else if (Operative == "D")
{
    c = a/b;
    printf("Division value is %d",c);

}

else if (Operative == "S")
{
    c = a-b;
    printf("\nSubtraction value is %d",c);

}
```

}

Comment: It's a bit off topic but you should use `cout` and `cin` instead of `printf` and `scanf` in C++, also `std::string` container is more proper than char array.

Comment: You should be aware too that while you're code will compile it's not really C++.. you include C headers rather than their C++ equivalent, arrays of char rather than string, etc..

Comment: I'd suggest rewriting it using only [C++ headers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header)

Answer (score 3):

Use `strcmp` to compare strings values. `==` compares pointers:

```
if (strcmp (Operative,  "M") == 0) ...
```

Comment: so how do i properly declare the operative and also capture it during userinput.?

Comment: ,when i used "strcmp",it output the following error.:: 42 Calculator.cpp [Error] cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'int strcmp(const char*, const char*)'

Comment: @brayo - If you use an `std::string` you *can* use `==` for comparison. With a `char[]` you have to use `strcmp`. Decide on your types!

Comment: @brayo : you need to decide whether c or c++ for handling strings. For C see the answer and don't change ypur original code. For C++ change operation to std::string and use == operator to compare.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `cin.ignore()` (after `scanf`, before `gets`) first, because there is still `\0` in the buffer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `switch` statement.

```
 switch(operation){
        case 'P':
            result = a+b;
            printf("%d + %d = %d", a,b,result);
            .
            .
            .
```

Comment: i hadn't declared std::string at the top,i still used == to compare.Also because i was missing cin.ignore() after after scanf.it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Just code this in your `int main()` if you prefer to use `printf` and `scanf` you replace and everything will be ok.

```
do {

        cout << "Option 1 <<endl;
        cout << "Option 2 <<endl;
        cout << "Option 3 <<endl;

        cin >> x;

        switch (x) {
            case 1:
                //Your operation here
                break;
            case 2:
                //Your operation here
                 break;
            case 3:
                //Your operation here
                break;
            case 4:
                exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                cout << "Input a valid option" <<endl;
    }

    } while(x);
```